# Helvetica Neue rendering strangely in IE7

Tags: css, fonts, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to do some cross browser maintenance and I am having trouble with the appearance of a font in IE7. I am have no experience in cross browser testing so forgive me if I am being stupid. I am using the bootstrap.min.css and the fonts defined in the body are:

```
body{margin:0;font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;color:#333333;background-color:#ffffff;}
```

The default Helvetica Neue works fine on my dev machine which is a Mac, but when I test using Crossover on IE7 the font is extremely hard to see, is this just a bad version of the font on windows? If it is can I define a way that it does not get used in IE7? This is what the font looks like. [image]

If I put Arial ahead of Helvetica Neue the font appears better but then it changes the appearance on other browsers. I'm pretty lost and would appreciate some help thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have Helvetica Neue on the windows machine? I can't see from your code but are you importing the font properly if you're using a web font?

Comment: Don't spend much time getting a font to work in IE7. You'll never get a ROI.

Comment: @alimac83 I'm using Crossover to run IE7 on a Mac so I am not sure if I am importing the font correctly. AlienWebguy thanks, I'll do my best on it but I won't stress too much over it. I'd just like to solve it.

Comment: I agree with Alien though - take a look at this :-) http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-18440979

Comment: that's wierd. quick fix: add `*font-family:Arial, sans-serif` to the body declaration above (after initial font-family). Hack only hits IE <= 7 which should be enough(?)

Comment: I think it's a Mac system font, but I don't know what is rendering in Crossover IE if it doesn't have it. Surely Arial would be used.

Comment: @inrbob The hack seems to override the previous family in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most computers have no font named “Helvetica Neue”, and what happens in almost all installations of IE 7 in your case is that Arial is used instead.

If this does not happen, then the situation is affected either by some CSS code other than the disclosed code or, in your case, by the Crossover software. I would bet on the latter—the software might be trying to use the Helvetica Neue font in your system and failing to do so properly. In any case, this is most probably relevant in your development environment only. Just test the page on real IE in a real Windows system.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I'll have a look when I can get my hands on one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use font-face for cross browser compatibility. "Helvetica Neue" is not web safe font, so it's being rendered depending on whether it is available on viewers system. If it's not, then the next font in the row is rendered, in this case its probably Arial.

Answer (score 1):

Use the star hack to target IE7

body {
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
*font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

Comment: I was trying the hacks earlier, for some reason, Arial gets rendered in the browser that does support Helvetica Neue :( might just have to use Arial primarily.

Comment: Typically Helvetica Neue is only on OS X, and Helvetica is on PC. Maybe you have a corrupted font? Maybe test on another machine.